# block by cookie when scraping Walmart

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, cookies, request

I have a code which will scrape Walmart. it will input about 100 zip codes for each products(300 intotal) and scrape the corresponding price. I test it with 3 product url and 2 zipcode and it should give my six data. It works well when i run the code wihhout proxy service.
The output is like this:

```
43819800,041167412213,10003,3520,19.96,2022-07-05 14:06:47
43819800,041167412213,48104,5472,19.96,2022-07-05 14:06:47
224749468,300450206909,10003,3520,42.47,2022-07-05 14:06:49
224749468,300450206909,48104,5472,42.47,2022-07-05 14:06:50
14053317,681131187091,10003,3520,2.52,2022-07-05 14:06:51
14053317,681131187091,48104,5472,2.52,2022-07-05 14:06:52
```

I know eventually if i want to run it for large amount of products, i need proxy service so i buy one. But when i run the code with proxy service, most data will missing.

I guess the reason why i cannot get all data is because cookie problem. I guess cookies= will expire and i do not know how to generated a new and correct one. Do anyone knows how to handle cookies problem when scraping Walmart? Any help appreciated, thanks!

Following is my code

```
def main(url_list, zip_code_list, ip_list, _now, save_dict, num, csv_list, utc_tz):
    _dict = {}
    debug = False
    s = requests.Session()

    output_json_file = f'backup/{num}_' + _now.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M.json")
    output_csv_file = f'backup/{num}_' + _now.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M.csv")

    flag = True

    if debug:
        url_list = [
            'https://www.target.com/p/claritin-24-hour-non-drowsy-allergy-relief-tablets-loratadine/-/A-80354268?preselect=14351285#lnk=sametab',
            'https://www.target.com/p/genexa-dextromethorphan-kids-39-cough-and-chest-congestion-suppressant-4-fl-oz/-/A-80130848#lnk=sametab'
            # 'https://www.target.com/p/claritin-24-hour-non-drowsy-allergy-relief-tablets-loratadine/-/A-80354268?preselect=14351285#lnk=sametab'
        ]
        zip_code_list = [
            10005,
        ]
    i = 0
    for _url in url_list:
        for zip_code in zip_code_list:
            # proxy service
            proxies = {"http": None, "https": None}
            # proxies = {
            ...,
            ...}

            i += 1
            _dict[i] = {}
            start_time = time.perf_counter()

            try:
                item = _url.split("/")[-1]  # A-80354268?preselect=14351285#lnk=sametab or A-80130848#lnk=sametab
                url_type = 1
                page_num = item

                if '?' in item:
                    url_type = 3
                    item2 = item.split("?")
                    page_num = item2[0]
                else:
                    pass
            except Exception as e:
                end_time = time.perf_counter()
                continue

            zip_code_url = "https://www.walmart.com/orchestra/home/graphql"

            payload = json.dumps({
                "query": "......",
                "variables": {
                    "input": {
                        "postalCode": str(zip_code),
                        "accessTypes": [
                            "PICKUP_INSTORE",
                            "PICKUP_CURBSIDE",
                            "PICKUP_SPOKE",
                            "PICKUP_POPUP"
                        ],
                        "nodeTypes": [
                            "STORE",
                            "PICKUP_SPOKE",
                            "PICKUP_POPUP"
                        ],
                        "latitude": None,
                        "longitude": None,
                        "radius": None
                    },
                    "checkItemAvailability": False,
                    "checkWeeklyReservation": False,
                    "enableStoreSelectorMarketplacePickup": False
                }
            })
            headers = {
                'authority': 'www.walmart.com',
                'pragma': 'no-cache',
                'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                'x-o-segment': 'oaoh',
                'x-o-correlation-id': 'Tt33HoVZ_Pqtlie1ABII1nfekFaSEtbRQPSc',
                'device_profile_ref_id': '-f6R8qf8Vd3gwky1UOzoEwW_XoTeRKqppMfK',
                'x-latency-trace': '1',
                'wm_mp': 'true',
                'wm_page_url': 'https://www.walmart.com/ip/Allegra-Adult-24HR-Gelcaps-24-Ct-180-mg-Allergy-Relief/43819800',
                'x-o-platform-version': 'main-1.2.0-3a465c',
                'x-o-gql-query': 'query nearByNodes',
                'x-o-bu': 'WALMART-US',
                'x-apollo-operation-name': 'nearByNodes',
                'traceparent': 'Tt33HoVZ_Pqtlie1ABII1nfekFaSEtbRQPSc',
                'x-o-mart': 'B2C',
                'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.82 Safari/537.36',
                'x-o-platform': 'rweb',
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'accept': 'application/json',
                'x-enable-server-timing': '1',
                'x-o-ccm': 'server',
                'wm_qos.correlation_id': 'Tt33HoVZ_Pqtlie1ABII1nfekFaSEtbRQPSc',
                'origin': 'https://www.walmart.com',
                'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
                'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
                'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
                'referer': 'https://www.walmart.com/ip/Allegra-Adult-24HR-Gelcaps-24-Ct-180-mg-Allergy-Relief/43819800',
                'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7',
                'cookie': '_pxvid=10811607-f238-11ec-a720-4e756c594d76; ACID=2263b9c6-4e5a-44ce-a9da-05e028a9b8c7; hasACID=true; vtc=ShJZRQkr5ADHxW2cc6mpW0; TBV=7; adblocked=false; locGuestData=eyJpbnRlbnQiOiJTSElQUElORyIsImlzRXhwbGljaXQiOmZhbHNlLCJzdG9yZUludGVudCI6IlBJQ0tVUCIsIm1lcmdlRmxhZyI6ZmFsc2UsImlzRGVmYXVsdGVkIjpmYWxzZSwicGlja3VwIjp7Im5vZGVJZCI6IjMwODEiLCJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE2NTU5MDgzNjMwNTF9LCJwb3N0YWxDb2RlIjp7InRpbWVzdGFtcCI6MTY1NTkwODM2MzA1MSwiYmFzZSI6Ijk1ODI5In0sInZhbGlkYXRlS2V5IjoicHJvZDp2MjoyMjYzYjljNi00ZTVhLTQ0Y2UtYTlkYS0wNWUwMjhhOWI4YzcifQ%3D%3D; tb_sw_supported=false; auth=MTAyOTYyMDE4fNO1docV1h53scwTVZ09zkq8CMnyd0xQJ2B%2BWcsOyT6LROWRUsmVs%2Bp%2BqdGXlTGcs43hwU%2BCNtvvfjRjs7lCjIvrK3NOp%2FSayADm%2FauT3or57dQr8nIRizNO0Go9X0h5767wuZloTfhm7Wk2KcjygsAEeU%2BeKCMhfP9XV060SY%2FgcNaenrudSCZlEFJXNSGF6XDQTWwNYV8JcXQmjWW2gCuRvXtkjUhxyHY9czMQpG4UMk70P8glgOEpLOprhDfMM%2FFHGZ2dCNmxWrdkwqEKrhrUOgaJ2pqn5A3SHetSvGPUoDKun8p%2FM%2BS69xpJ5GAkRAvQ9UuySW7l7kgiPOgyF60jwwfDPWGSAbjbNQ7pWssaQQ2kgt4PeOLZzshCiRmgr%2B51HN4wOouRjTjluv08HZE5WBBdZBCyKnCQAR7o6eg%3D; assortmentStoreId=3081; hasLocData=1; TB_Latency_Tracker_100=1; TB_Navigation_Preload_01=1; TB_SFOU-100=; bstc=bdAHA-WWcfXk0PMnP-uT0o; mobileweb=0; xpa=3Fi1g|3_gkh|3pRU7|4NCWH|55b29|5_9FA|DAwQd|Ecx7k|EjkLl|FYe-R|Hv6FZ|LTD5Y|LguYm|NbUbl|NoJl6|O1c3v|OuwKl|Pgtnl|Q-bGe|TMjj7|V0SkO|VAuQw|_hSAz|cL8HI|ccWng|cfVAR|duBe9|eEnay|eWARP|hGNr-|hPI48|hqy5q|jUi64|kFqfr|kLRY3|lQHtM|rdfjX|wGrec|zCylr; xpm=1%2B1656425217%2BShJZRQkr5ADHxW2cc6mpW0~%2B0; exp-ck=3_gkh24NCWH155b2925_9FA1DAwQd3Ecx7k1EjkLl1FYe-R1NbUbl1O1c3v1OuwKl1Pgtnl1V0SkO1_hSAz1cL8HI1ccWng2eEnay2eWARP1hGNr-1jUi641kFqfr1kLRY31lQHtM1; helpgql=1; _pxhd=f5c62b38667d2415146fc6f1cf93cdcc3327afc72fb672b6c09d362415e56f38:10811607-f238-11ec-a720-4e756c594d76; ak_bmsc=1BE44332F7F4F1A06C35DB50CE7A244A~000000000000000000000000000000~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; bm_sv=84EAF547030A90DB5BCD4679165B254D~YAAQLcMTAvZBZZeBAQAAthWjqhAc7AUJuL6t1BdztQNVwhWMVE5DVAXWjtGVZh8Xm0VgJ47u+ho0b3dkGGOwoGGOwbooZSpjcjxOOiEXIzTZgWRkQQeyTz5OB8ixRgE2Fqg1vQiCeOZkQWRmu+zj+P9ZwuNPusS4/dIStSfzYA4sDRQ6KPwQMqsMLFvPhDxjiR/ByNKugRT//CgOWQgb12FlDL5o/kJUQaRsUA00Dc9zKt/XUexTgCG91S5atV9iXQ==~1; locDataV3=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; _px3=fd4a806b205916413bf99a01e942ff9336232e851610f563e729bd8270721edd:bOVkbtqNZf6CXjv41nbl5RGLFNxuANcsgSOgoqttHpCpEzg2Mto0wjrxDFfh6zUSiA5wDDm5rTHKfX2lAiPg0Q==:1000:zDPkfwX/OSrZ75Ggjs1Krpm4L6f17sXBDANaE4TV+9j6Y6dnGPRddnxuV+8zV6iiq/iJexlqrtw3brpn59WivGDsHGwucjfO5cRyfNrUryok4xbUwr1yK/iAyP1t4vdvf8bS4jGOBM9xp8zMe44W7tOveajOsuF64IAfP4GPGNBGPUZkIE3I+bocrKQJA7sdD12/BOw6goT1VCddGHvnEQ==; QuantumMetricSessionID=18cfa4319b8ef1e79540e53bae1b9f4a; QuantumMetricUserID=86906ef3aba513b1593763543a679f7b; xptwg=3560776434:CF9364D4F670D8:21A39D6:281D1B4C:2C081154:A12BB2D4:; TS01b0be75=01538efd7cb337960d25ee6309ddbe2d9b73d42de4db21f151df666ad7ab7cde6a6e48b30e01e0ae9a71bdd492f4d3cefe3367d67f; TS013ed49a=01538efd7cb337960d25ee6309ddbe2d9b73d42de4db21f151df666ad7ab7cde6a6e48b30e01e0ae9a71bdd492f4d3cefe3367d67f; akavpau_p2=1656426003~id=7229bf055a987cf4ec0baf62877b3b53; _astc=f75dda122e22d06cf00905ef84d586f8; pxcts=f6d5b40e-f6eb-11ec-b18e-5746686f6a76; _pxff_cfp=1'            }

            try:
                response = requests.request("POST", zip_code_url, headers=headers, data=payload, proxies=proxies,timeout=10)
                content = response.json()
            except Exception as e:
                end_time = time.perf_counter()
                continue

            try:
                store_id = content['data']['nearByNodes']['nodes'][0]['id']
            except Exception as e:
                end_time = time.perf_counter()
                continue

            url2 = "https://www.walmart.com/orchestra/home/graphql/ip/"+page_num
            payload2 = json.dumps({
                "query": "...",
                "variables": {
                    "channel": "WWW",
                    "pageType": "ItemPageGlobal",
                    "tenant": "WM_GLASS",
                    "version": "v1",
                    "itemId": str(page_num),
                    "layout": [
                        "itemDesktop"
                    ],
                    "tempo": {
                        "targeting": "%7B%22userState%22%3A%22loggedIn%22%7D",
                        "params": [
                            {
                                "key": "expoVars",
                                "value": "expoVariationValue"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "expoVars",
                                "value": "expoVariationValue2"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "p13N": {
                        "reqId": "zAKgORT4feGddLyly5nLXRCH16egOJ0JwL4x",
                        "pageId": str(page_num),
                        "modules": [
                            {
                                "moduleType": "PersonalizedLabels",
                                "moduleId": "234-sdfsfvns-sdfdskvl"
                            }
                        ],
                        "userClientInfo": {
                            "ipAddress": "IP=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1-0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
                            "isZipLocated": True,
                            "callType": "CLIENT",
                            "deviceType": "desktop"
                        },
                        "userReqInfo": {
                            "refererContext": {
                                "source": "itempage"
                            },
                            "pageUrl": "/ip/Equate-Maximum-Strength-Severe-Allergy-Plus-Sinus-Headache-Caplets-20-Count/14053317"
                        }
                    },
                    "p13nCls": {
                        "pageId": str(page_num),
                        "userClientInfo": {
                            "ipAddress": "IP=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1-0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
                            "isZipLocated": True,
                            "deviceType": "desktop",
                            "callType": "CLIENT"
                        },
                        "userReqInfo": {
                            "refererContext": {
                                "source": "itempage"
                            }
                        },
                        "p13NCallType": "ATF"
                    },
                    "fetchBuyBoxAd": True,
                    "fetchSkyline": True,
                    "fetchIdml": True,
                    "fetchReviews": True,
                    "fetchFitment": True,
                    "fetchSEO": True,
                    "fetchP13N": True,
                    "fetchAffirm": True,
                    "fetchMarquee": True,
                    "fetchSpCarousel": True,
                    "fetchBrandBox": True,
                    "fetchDiscounts": False,
                    "enableItemIbotta": True
                }
            })
            headers2 = {
                'authority': 'www.walmart.com',
                'pragma': 'no-cache',
                'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="99"',
                'x-o-correlation-id': 'EtyZZHcTSBCiVMxl4i44a6h_Gzqf1F-MkpXd',
                'x-o-item-id': str(page_num),
                'device_profile_ref_id': '-1fXNwg-2wCxSXoXmzk8jg4T_XgDMMHhHTMN',
                'x-latency-trace': '1',
                'wm_mp': 'true',
                'wm_page_url': 'https://www.walmart.com/ip/Equate-Maximum-Strength-Severe-Allergy-Plus-Sinus-Headache-Caplets-20-Count/14053317',
                'x-o-platform-version': 'main-1.3.0-e51fc3',
                'x-o-segment': 'oaoh',
                'calltype': 'CLIENT',
                'x-o-gql-query': 'query ItemById',
                'x-o-bu': 'WALMART-US',
                'x-apollo-operation-name': 'ItemById',
                'ip-referer': '',
                'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
                'traceparent': 'EtyZZHcTSBCiVMxl4i44a6h_Gzqf1F-MkpXd',
                'x-o-mart': 'B2C',
                'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
                'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.82 Safari/537.36',
                'x-o-platform': 'rweb',
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'accept': 'application/json',
                'is-variant-fetch': 'false',
                'x-enable-server-timing': '1',
                'x-o-ccm': 'server',
                'wm_qos.correlation_id': 'EtyZZHcTSBCiVMxl4i44a6h_Gzqf1F-MkpXd',
                'origin': 'https://www.walmart.com',
                'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
                'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
                'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
                'referer': 'https://www.walmart.com/ip/Equate-Maximum-Strength-Severe-Allergy-Plus-Sinus-Headache-Caplets-20-Count/14053317',
                'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                'cookie': '_pxvid=10811607-f238-11ec-a720-4e756c594d76; ACID=2263b9c6-4e5a-44ce-a9da-05e028a9b8c7; hasACID=true; vtc=ShJZRQkr5ADHxW2cc6mpW0; TBV=7; adblocked=false; locGuestData=eyJpbnRlbnQiOiJTSElQUElORyIsImlzRXhwbGljaXQiOmZhbHNlLCJzdG9yZUludGVudCI6IlBJQ0tVUCIsIm1lcmdlRmxhZyI6ZmFsc2UsImlzRGVmYXVsdGVkIjpmYWxzZSwicGlja3VwIjp7Im5vZGVJZCI6IjMwODEiLCJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE2NTU5MDgzNjMwNTF9LCJwb3N0YWxDb2RlIjp7InRpbWVzdGFtcCI6MTY1NTkwODM2MzA1MSwiYmFzZSI6Ijk1ODI5In0sInZhbGlkYXRlS2V5IjoicHJvZDp2MjoyMjYzYjljNi00ZTVhLTQ0Y2UtYTlkYS0wNWUwMjhhOWI4YzcifQ%3D%3D; tb_sw_supported=false; auth=MTAyOTYyMDE4fNO1docV1h53scwTVZ09zkq8CMnyd0xQJ2B%2BWcsOyT6LROWRUsmVs%2Bp%2BqdGXlTGcs43hwU%2BCNtvvfjRjs7lCjIvrK3NOp%2FSayADm%2FauT3or57dQr8nIRizNO0Go9X0h5767wuZloTfhm7Wk2KcjygsAEeU%2BeKCMhfP9XV060SY%2FgcNaenrudSCZlEFJXNSGF6XDQTWwNYV8JcXQmjWW2gCuRvXtkjUhxyHY9czMQpG4UMk70P8glgOEpLOprhDfMM%2FFHGZ2dCNmxWrdkwqEKrhrUOgaJ2pqn5A3SHetSvGPUoDKun8p%2FM%2BS69xpJ5GAkRAvQ9UuySW7l7kgiPOgyF60jwwfDPWGSAbjbNQ7pWssaQQ2kgt4PeOLZzshCiRmgr%2B51HN4wOouRjTjluv08HZE5WBBdZBCyKnCQAR7o6eg%3D; assortmentStoreId=3081; hasLocData=1; TB_Latency_Tracker_100=1; TB_Navigation_Preload_01=1; TB_SFOU-100=; bstc=bdAHA-WWcfXk0PMnP-uT0o; mobileweb=0; xpa=3Fi1g|3_gkh|3pRU7|4NCWH|55b29|5_9FA|DAwQd|Ecx7k|EjkLl|FYe-R|Hv6FZ|LTD5Y|LguYm|NbUbl|NoJl6|O1c3v|OuwKl|Pgtnl|Q-bGe|TMjj7|V0SkO|VAuQw|_hSAz|cL8HI|ccWng|cfVAR|duBe9|eEnay|eWARP|hGNr-|hPI48|hqy5q|jUi64|kFqfr|kLRY3|lQHtM|rdfjX|wGrec|zCylr; xpm=1%2B1656425217%2BShJZRQkr5ADHxW2cc6mpW0~%2B0; exp-ck=3_gkh24NCWH155b2925_9FA1DAwQd3Ecx7k1EjkLl1FYe-R1NbUbl1O1c3v1OuwKl1Pgtnl1V0SkO1_hSAz1cL8HI1ccWng2eEnay2eWARP1hGNr-1jUi641kFqfr1kLRY31lQHtM1; helpgql=1; _pxhd=f5c62b38667d2415146fc6f1cf93cdcc3327afc72fb672b6c09d362415e56f38:10811607-f238-11ec-a720-4e756c594d76; ak_bmsc=1BE44332F7F4F1A06C35DB50CE7A244A~000000000000000000000000000000~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; bm_sv=84EAF547030A90DB5BCD4679165B254D~YAAQLcMTAvZBZZeBAQAAthWjqhAc7AUJuL6t1BdztQNVwhWMVE5DVAXWjtGVZh8Xm0VgJ47u+ho0b3dkGGOwoGGOwbooZSpjcjxOOiEXIzTZgWRkQQeyTz5OB8ixRgE2Fqg1vQiCeOZkQWRmu+zj+P9ZwuNPusS4/dIStSfzYA4sDRQ6KPwQMqsMLFvPhDxjiR/ByNKugRT//CgOWQgb12FlDL5o/kJUQaRsUA00Dc9zKt/XUexTgCG91S5atV9iXQ==~1; locDataV3=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; _px3=fd4a806b205916413bf99a01e942ff9336232e851610f563e729bd8270721edd:bOVkbtqNZf6CXjv41nbl5RGLFNxuANcsgSOgoqttHpCpEzg2Mto0wjrxDFfh6zUSiA5wDDm5rTHKfX2lAiPg0Q==:1000:zDPkfwX/OSrZ75Ggjs1Krpm4L6f17sXBDANaE4TV+9j6Y6dnGPRddnxuV+8zV6iiq/iJexlqrtw3brpn59WivGDsHGwucjfO5cRyfNrUryok4xbUwr1yK/iAyP1t4vdvf8bS4jGOBM9xp8zMe44W7tOveajOsuF64IAfP4GPGNBGPUZkIE3I+bocrKQJA7sdD12/BOw6goT1VCddGHvnEQ==; QuantumMetricSessionID=18cfa4319b8ef1e79540e53bae1b9f4a; QuantumMetricUserID=86906ef3aba513b1593763543a679f7b; xptwg=3560776434:CF9364D4F670D8:21A39D6:281D1B4C:2C081154:A12BB2D4:; TS01b0be75=01538efd7cb337960d25ee6309ddbe2d9b73d42de4db21f151df666ad7ab7cde6a6e48b30e01e0ae9a71bdd492f4d3cefe3367d67f; TS013ed49a=01538efd7cb337960d25ee6309ddbe2d9b73d42de4db21f151df666ad7ab7cde6a6e48b30e01e0ae9a71bdd492f4d3cefe3367d67f; akavpau_p2=1656426003~id=7229bf055a987cf4ec0baf62877b3b53; _astc=f75dda122e22d06cf00905ef84d586f8; pxcts=f6d5b40e-f6eb-11ec-b18e-5746686f6a76; _pxff_cfp=1'
            }
            try:
                response2 = requests.request("POST", url2, headers=headers2, data=payload2, proxies=proxies,timeout=10)
                content2 = response2.json()
            except Exception as e:
                end_time = time.perf_counter()
                continue

            _now2 = datetime.datetime.now(tz=utc_tz)

            try:
                product_price = content2['data']['product']['priceInfo']['currentPrice']['price']

            except Exception as e:
                product_price = None

            try:
                product_gtin = content2['data']['product']['upc']
            except Exception as e:
                product_gtin = None
            try:
                pruduct_time = _now2.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                _dict[i] = {
                    'page_num': page_num,
                    'product_gtin': product_gtin,
                    'store_id': store_id,
                    'product_price': product_price,
                    'zip_code': zip_code,
                    'pruduct_time': pruduct_time
                }

                with open(output_csv_file, "a", encoding='utf-8') as fw2:
                    new_line = f'{page_num},{product_gtin},{zip_code},{store_id},{product_price},{pruduct_time}\n'
                    fw2.write(new_line)
                    if output_csv_file not in csv_list:
                        csv_list.append(output_csv_file)
                    end_time = time.perf_counter()
            except Exception as e:
                end_time = time.perf_counter()

    # print(_dict)
    with open(output_json_file, "w", encoding='utf-8') as fw3:
        fw3.write(json.dumps(_dict))
    save_dict[num] = _dict
    return _dict


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # output_csv_file = 'output.csv'

    if not os.path.exists('output'):
        os.makedirs('output')
    else:
        pass
    if not os.path.exists('backup'):
        os.makedirs('backup')
    else:
        pass
    utc_tz = pytz.timezone('UTC')
    _now = datetime.datetime.now(tz=utc_tz)

    ip_list = [
        '45.142.28.83:8094',
        '45.137.60.112:6640',
    ]
    url_list = [
        # 'https://www.walmart.com/browse/health/allergy-and-sinus/976760_3771182',
        'https://www.walmart.com/ip/Allegra-Adult-24HR-Gelcaps-24-Ct-180-mg-Allergy-Relief/43819800',
        'https://www.walmart.com/ip/Zyrtec-24-Hour-Allergy-Relief-Tablets-with-10-mg-Cetirizine-HCl-90-ct/224749468?athbdg=L1600',
        'https://www.walmart.com/ip/Equate-Maximum-Strength-Severe-Allergy-Plus-Sinus-Headache-Caplets-20-Count/14053317'
    ]
    zip_code_list = [
        10003,
        48104
    ]

    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    save_dict = {}

    thread_num = 1
    one_thread_url_num = 3
    pool = threadpool.ThreadPool(thread_num)

    param_list = []
    csv_list = []
    for i in range(thread_num):
        save_dict[i + 1] = {}
        start_url_num = i * one_thread_url_num
        end_url_num = start_url_num + one_thread_url_num
        if end_url_num >= len(url_list):
            param_list.append(([url_list[start_url_num:], zip_code_list, ip_list, _now, save_dict, i + 1,
                                csv_list, utc_tz], None))
            print("start_url_num", start_url_num, end_url_num)

        else:
            param_list.append(([url_list[start_url_num:end_url_num], zip_code_list, ip_list, _now, save_dict, i + 1,
                                csv_list, utc_tz], None))
            print("start_url_num", start_url_num, len(url_list))
    tasks = threadpool.makeRequests(main, param_list)
    [pool.putRequest(task) for task in tasks]

    pool.wait()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help, but they use a crazy amount of cookies. The following works on my system, but you would have to check in your proxy if it still works:

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'TB_Latency_Tracker_100': '1',
    'TB_Navigation_Preload_01': '1',
    'TB_SFOU-100': '',
    'vtc': 'XlaYVaEkh8T8kzzvS_hIbk',
    'bstc': 'XlaYVaEkh8T8kzzvS_hIbk',
    'mobileweb': '0',
    'xpa': '2Oqb6|3_gkh|4NCWH|4QHB7|77hfu|BIcmp|CN28l|DAwQd|E4WND|FYe-R|LTD5Y|LguYm|PNKHT|Q-bGe|Uf0oj|V0SkO|VQW_o|ZZeL5|_hSAz|_nCIe|cfVAR|fSXlM|fsM8g|gVG-b|hPI48|hqy5q|mrxWN|myr6S|nzyw-|u_9Xw|uru_L|w_GEw|xCzID|yQ2ZK|ymjfc|yxNJ6',
    'xpm': '1%2B1657553050%2BXlaYVaEkh8T8kzzvS_hIbk~%2B0',
    'exp-ck': '3_gkh24NCWH177hfu1DAwQd3E4WND1FYe-R1V0SkO1VQW_o1_hSAz1fsM8g1gVG-b1nzyw-1u_9Xw1w_GEw1yxNJ63',
    '_pxhd': '50d3bc3fa5826eff6126ffc7af49a2537ce11bb3e08dd63bd36c5d81bf0bd889:836e203e-012d-11ed-ab53-626a69424550',
    'TS01b0be75': '01538efd7cc6666f1a2641aa6310df48b0aa83bef1d4e8c021bebea253322db7f36548b6555ae1f2d25935d08c0152b6e024d98a68',
    'TS013ed49a': '01538efd7c23b1cfcf8ec2a792dcc79a4900439ee48c91b75191292f79f95af4844015f66e746c23c227f7624f91d1aa5a91748452',
    'ak_bmsc': 'CB7DC8666D2ADCC2DA7D98F41C4E9A7C~000000000000000000000000000000~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',
    'AID': 'wmlspartner%253D0%253Areflectorid%253D0000000000000000000000%253Alastupd%253D1657553061915',
    'com.wm.reflector': '"reflectorid:0000000000000000000000@lastupd:1657553501450@firstcreate:1657553050889"',
    'auth': 'MTAyOTYyMDE4iuXLjWxh0mezZct6vG1mZ4wY6TQw3O%2BIEPH4NvDUyfhmu69uFbbN7n5Ot9VlhfxBLpViBXYhsdueTzHZvs4wQ6kPF6QDAwmzlx0pLYyOU0rtymbnequDBQLbnVN3KRJI767wuZloTfhm7Wk2KcjygjFwIZIekXC4wlSRgDWHtlx2%2B7u9g5NTsQKQz7FjX7I1EGqBWHzo5aIFd840Vx0asLvXA71KfiseySlLrBNPmhgUMk70P8glgOEpLOprhDfMM%2FFHGZ2dCNmxWrdkwqEKro2YwNEhLNUXBJiHjR181XWEdsdURjqSmrNlL12kr9b5bVWucTpKvbLLYqopaNh%2BgMUjRmku4Mft2op72ZGvimBOMeROjxWV0iYNj7aJ1x%2BzjCy5WWSQ4FE4inBBtr0Bo0jyrOXbKKhH072NS%2FW0j%2FU%3D',
    'ACID': 'a24c281a-1f90-4388-9f48-31e6845bed35',
    'hasACID': 'true',
    'assortmentStoreId': '3081',
    'hasLocData': '1',
    'helpgql': '1',
    'xptwg': '4235111632:1423B1873CDF6C0:342F2AE:564BAE52:5BF31DF4:A280DF5:',
    'akavpau_p2': '1657554102~id=6fbfd710b5fb2c3f267671836a21ec64',
    'TBV': '7',
    '_astc': '659a26f43e57a7d07a8c8bdd26c6b359',
    'adblocked': 'false',
    'pxcts': '849193ee-012d-11ed-8c9e-5a504d7a4563',
    '_pxvid': '836e203e-012d-11ed-ab53-626a69424550',
    'bm_sv': 'EFB76C439E0BFA2E7F8687F86EAECD61~YAAQluXKF9rngt2BAQAANZ7c7RBjHSuRhZ3PpiZhjaxEsgd657ef8/UgREPshx0Cz2F8DS+VuFuaNl9E3dUTTL2JDpsOkhKl5URBoGmA51ygaSk4uHNzIwyHfifRojFGEVjBWOZRFsEH0YIGLyYs1T733sNKaMJVsUUoTvKT56mIorJz4/U0MOGJ5dCRIACqtWmTzwPfjaLdu6aysln026JlI3w+qZWG87OWlVERzynoD1CGduLg9C+5ygeQV++lLQ==~1',
    'locDataV3': '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%3D',
    'locGuestData': 'eyJpbnRlbnQiOiJTSElQUElORyIsImlzRXhwbGljaXQiOmZhbHNlLCJzdG9yZUludGVudCI6IlBJQ0tVUCIsIm1lcmdlRmxhZyI6ZmFsc2UsImlzRGVmYXVsdGVkIjpmYWxzZSwicGlja3VwIjp7Im5vZGVJZCI6IjMwODEiLCJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE2NTc1NTMwNTM5MDd9LCJwb3N0YWxDb2RlIjp7InRpbWVzdGFtcCI6MTY1NzU1MzA1MzkwNywiYmFzZSI6Ijk1ODI5In0sInZhbGlkYXRlS2V5IjoicHJvZDp2MjphMjRjMjgxYS0xZjkwLTQzODgtOWY0OC0zMWU2ODQ1YmVkMzUifQ%3D%3D',
    'tb_sw_supported': 'false',
    '_px3': 'b96dfc6014fef380ad61cba68edbb676a83bf96c08ace0fda65c124c5bb282f0:BcNRGhHVyi6rRnjCpbHQUZk2ba5rJozuHoI9cpD/ZshcLZGLfp6RPy9RgdHILyBZDt2du2mgnfsF9NaCeZ5Dqw==:1000:HpsN85rY5JiFHvRBWBDAyFZMrE2ZpvUERcQXxcJYT+PI1Gi4icLg46Syz8Qftk9WEMmKyX2PhdUKiKQhL/qM+8ahFkevvMzmt8m3dmgCUxKjX6Mx06qXFDkRhQ7F1CzxjWv5s2kSsoKKcKpX7+eS1iGuJTYupe7ul2kJoevEo4PfHCvshjOslShXYV68jvpYi12bj5ns3F3KZVla4cJt7A==',
    'bm_mi': '66E015F2E445D4C81204D96C3D0C3D23~YAAQluXKF7Lngt2BAQAAOorc7RDr+Aekmj6zMgMRnKrKdc/NMpos2kYtJ9j4jzVaZDGgfmxmZgC6bar/eW1FwpJGK0C70OHLBmE1l0qosu6sU8q+Jo0qkyHyB00hfNQPuCECBqJgVpraqpDvbQHJRMudMM8gZWovGhuVEVEhduzRBDxYFdln4IQL0M4PNGxUdwZNG99tZjKuReZsdlhdJbnMbGXOrqsTRFtT3B3G45TRVScdeOvZb1uBzdThLJ6OZjK1bra2xFwcmn6ZKJba5dawbMtKnGJabXMSdQgjY6BQO6tGAOPA+ylMwO9Ga3XhmxuFt4C4xbIQlR6acolnQtCN3HFBek9M6+FEtJdXSWk7rnTb5GKuZPDM5XWRiUyQsoxeAPwoi9WdpUEhJXSTwyU=~1',
    'QuantumMetricSessionID': '09e77a0583174de68d659cee4b8e3db3',
    'QuantumMetricUserID': 'efd78f6a336a0b4eaa53debc222de35f',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Referer': 'https://www.walmart.com/ip/Allegra-Adult-24HR-Gelcaps-24-Ct-180-mg-Allergy-Relief/43819800',
    'x-o-segment': 'oaoh',
    'x-o-platform-version': 'main-1.5.1-fda6c9',
    'x-o-correlation-id': 'gevwerO9jaBLQSLIYQU6Vaqv0gkPbvW8_FEg',
    'wm_qos.correlation_id': 'gevwerO9jaBLQSLIYQU6Vaqv0gkPbvW8_FEg',
    'WM_MP': 'true',
    'x-o-ccm': 'server',
    'x-o-gql-query': 'query AdV2',
    'X-APOLLO-OPERATION-NAME': 'AdV2',
    'x-latency-trace': '1',
    'x-enable-server-timing': '1',
    'traceparent': 'gevwerO9jaBLQSLIYQU6Vaqv0gkPbvW8_FEg',
    'WM_PAGE_URL': 'https://www.walmart.com/ip/Allegra-Adult-24HR-Gelcaps-24-Ct-180-mg-Allergy-Relief/43819800',
    'DEVICE_PROFILE_REF_ID': 'uJjWx6XzZhYBFtUjd8BJmPf1j6eE5EV3woob',
    'x-o-platform': 'rweb',
    'x-o-bu': 'WALMART-US',
    'x-o-mart': 'B2C',
    'Origin': 'https://www.walmart.com',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
}

json_data = {
    'query': 'query AdV2( $platform:Platform! $pageId:String! $pageType:PageType! $tenant:String! $moduleType:ModuleType! $pageContext:PageContextIn $locationContext:LocationContextIn $moduleConfigs:JSON $adsContext:AdsContextIn $adRequestComposite:AdRequestCompositeIn ){adV2( platform:$platform pageId:$pageId pageType:$pageType tenant:$tenant moduleType:$moduleType locationContext:$locationContext pageContext:$pageContext moduleConfigs:$moduleConfigs adsContext:$adsContext adRequestComposite:$adRequestComposite ){status adContent{type data{__typename...AdDataDisplayAdFragment __typename...AdDataSponsoredProductsFragment}}}}fragment AdDataDisplayAdFragment on AdData{...on DisplayAd{json status}}fragment AdDataSponsoredProductsFragment on AdData{...on SponsoredProducts{adUuid adExpInfo moduleInfo products{...ProductFragment}}}fragment ProductFragment on Product{usItemId offerId badges{flags{__typename...on BaseBadge{id text key query type}...on PreviouslyPurchasedBadge{id text key lastBoughtOn numBought criteria{name value}}}labels{__typename...on BaseBadge{id text key}...on PreviouslyPurchasedBadge{id text key lastBoughtOn numBought}}tags{__typename...on BaseBadge{id text key}}}priceInfo{priceDisplayCodes{rollback reducedPrice eligibleForAssociateDiscount clearance strikethrough submapType priceDisplayCondition unitOfMeasure pricePerUnitUom}currentPrice{price priceString}wasPrice{price priceString}priceRange{minPrice maxPrice priceString}unitPrice{price priceString}}showOptions sponsoredProduct{spQs clickBeacon spTags}canonicalUrl numberOfReviews averageRating availabilityStatus imageInfo{thumbnailUrl allImages{id url}}name fulfillmentBadge classType type showAtc p13nData{predictedQuantity flags{PREVIOUSLY_PURCHASED{text}CUSTOMERS_PICK{text}}labels{PREVIOUSLY_PURCHASED{text}CUSTOMERS_PICK{text}}}}',
    'variables': {
        'adRequestComposite': {},
        'adsContext': {
            'locationContext': {
                'zipCode': '95829',
                'stateCode': 'CA',
                'storeId': '3081',
                'pickupStore': '3081',
                'deliveryStore': '3081',
                'intent': 'SHIPPING',
                'incatchment': True,
            },
            'itemId': '43819800',
            'categoryId': '976760_3771182_1291980',
            'categoryName': 'Health/Allergy and Sinus/Fexofenadine',
            'brand': 'Allegra',
            'productName': 'Allegra Adult 24HR Gelcaps (24 Ct, 180 mg), Allergy Relief',
            'productTypeId': '1278',
            'normKeyword': '',
            'verticalId': '',
            'dedupeList': [],
        },
        'pageContext': {
            'itemContext': {
                'itemId': '43819800',
                'categoryPath': '0:976760:3771182:1291980',
                'categoryPathName': 'Home Page/Health/Allergy and Sinus/Fexofenadine',
                'name': 'Allegra Adult 24HR Gelcaps (24 Ct, 180 mg), Allergy Relief',
                'brand': 'Allegra',
                'partTypeID': '',
                'manufactureNumber': '553243830',
                'aaiaBrand': '',
                'tireSize': '',
                'speedRating': '',
                'loadIndex': '',
                'viscosity': '',
                'type': 'VARIANT',
                'productTypeId': '1278',
            },
        },
        'pageId': '43819800',
        'pageType': 'ITEM',
        'platform': 'DESKTOP',
        'tenant': 'WM_GLASS',
        'locationContext': {
            'storeId': '3081',
            'stateCode': 'CA',
            'zipCode': '95829',
        },
        'moduleConfigs': {
            'moduleLocation': 'middle',
            'lazy': '1500',
        },
        'moduleType': 'SponsoredProductCarousel',
    },
}

response = requests.post('https://www.walmart.com/orchestra/home/graphql', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, json=json_data)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will have a try

Comment: I could not get it to work but when used headers/cookies from above it works (scrapping Walmart products)

Answer (score 0):

For Walmart scraping you can use [Walmart Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/walmart-search-api) alternative from a third-party API SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

It will bypass blocks (including CAPTCHA) from Google and other search engines, and no need to create the parser and maintain it.

Each store has its own `Location cookies`. You can learn more about it at [scrape Walmart Search for a specific store](https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-walmart-search-results-for-a-specific-store-id-with-plain-http-requests/#location-cookies) blog post.

You can get information from any store using the [JSON list of supported Walmart Stores](https://serpapi.com/walmart-stores) (4,640 in total):

```py
# https://serpapi.com/walmart-stores
with open("walmart-stores.json", "r") as file:
  walmart_stores = json.load(file)
```

In order to collect information from all pages, you need to use pagination, in our case using a `while` loop:

```py
if 'next' in results.get('serpapi_pagination', {}):
    search.params_dict.update(dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(results.get('serpapi_pagination', {}).get('next')).query)))
else:
    break
```

Check code in online [IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-walmart-data-pagination-serpapi#main.py).

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
from urllib.parse import (parse_qsl, urlsplit)
import os, json

# https://serpapi.com/walmart-stores
with open("walmart-stores.json", "r") as file:
  walmart_stores = json.load(file)
data = []
for store in walmart_stores[:2]:          # get data from first two stores, remove list slicing to get them all
    params = {
        "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),  # serpapi key, https://serpapi.com/manage-api-key 
        "engine": "walmart",              # serpapi parser engine
        "query": "Coffee",                # search query
        "store_id": store["store_id"]     # store ID to filter the products by the specific store only
    }
    search = GoogleSearch(params)         # where data extraction happens
    
    page_num = 0
    
    while True:
        results = search.get_dict()       # JSON -> Python dictionary
    
        for organic_result in results.get("organic_results", []):
            title = organic_result.get("title")
            price = organic_result.get("primary_offer").get("offer_price")
            product_page_url = organic_result.get("product_page_url")
            description = organic_result.get("description")
            thumbnail = organic_result.get("thumbnail")
            rating = organic_result.get("rating")
            reviews = organic_result.get("reviews")
    
            data.append({
                "page": page_num,
                "title": title,
                "price": price,
                "description": description,
                "thumbnail": thumbnail,
                "rating": rating,
                "reviews": reviews,
                "product_page_url": product_page_url
            })
                        
        page_num += 1
        print(page_num)
        
        if 'next' in results.get('serpapi_pagination', {}):
            search.params_dict.update(dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(results.get('serpapi_pagination', {}).get('next')).query)))
        else:
            break
        
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Example output:

```json
[
    {
    "page": 16,
    "title": "McCafe Breakfast Blend Ground Coffee, Medium Roast, 30 oz Canister",
    "price": 12.98,
    "description": "mccafe",
    "thumbnail": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/abe0e725-c650-4fd7-8efa-6869f9f5a716.ffdb20396c65dd75ca51af0f7737e299.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff",
    "rating": 4.8,
    "reviews": 437,
    "product_page_url": "https://www.walmart.com/ip/McCafe-Breakfast-Blend-Ground-Coffee-Medium-Roast-30-oz-Canister/171903071"
  },
  {
    "page": 16,
    "title": "Coffee",
    "price": 20.97,
    "description": "Art-inspired glass cutting boards deliver gorgeous kitchen art and will prove an essential item for food prep! Durable glass surface with smooth beveled glass edges is suitable for ceramic knife use.",
    "thumbnail": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/87f3d528-8e63-4e26-99bc-dfc5dd5d8a93.ff099b1c5c7d911adb4719a006e0be6b.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff",
    "rating": 0,
    "reviews": 0,
    "product_page_url": "https://www.walmart.com/ip/Coffee/741199677"
  },
  other results...
]
```

There's a [SerpApi Demo Project: Walmart Coffee Exploratory Data Analysis](https://serpapi.com/blog/serpapi-demo-project-walmart-coffee-exploratory-data-analysis/) blog post that shows coffee listings data extraction from 500 stores using pagination (inside each store).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.